# Iterative approach: Validating a binary search tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

```py
def is_bst(node)
    q = [node]
    while q:
        node = q.pop(0)
        if node:
            if node.left:
                if not node.left.data < node.data:
                    return False 
                q.append(node.left)
            if node.right:
                if not node.right.data > node.data:
                    return False
            q.append(node.right)
    return True 

is_bst(root)
```

On educative.io I worked on this practice problem (paywall), but the gist was that this code didn't work consistently produce the right answers. Their solution used a recursive algorithm. I'd like to know, is it possible to check if a BST is valid iteratively, and if no, what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Do an inorder traversal (using a stack to avoid recursion). And see if all the elements visited in the traversal are in sorted order.

Comment: Oh, so level order is whats tripping me up! So obvious in hindsight, thanks!

Comment: Re, "recursive" vs "iterative." Any algorithm that walks a tree must use an auxiliary data structure to remember which parts of the tree have been visited, and which have not. If it's a _depth-first_ tree walk, then the auxiliary structure can be a stack, and if it's a stack, then it can be implicit in the local variables of a recursive function. (I.e., implicit on the call stack.) For a _breadth-first_ tree walk, the auxiliary structure must be an explicit FIFO queue, and for a _non_-recursive, depth-first walk, it must be an explicit stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to check if a BST is valid iteratively

Yes

> what has gone wrong here?

Your code only compares a node's value with its direct parent, but even if that test passes for all child-parent pairs, it is not enough to validate a BST. For instance, this tree is not a valid BST, even though all parent-child pairs pass the comparison test:

```
             4
            / \
           1   8
          / \
         0   5
```

The value 5 is in violation with the value 4, as *all* values in the left subtree must not be greater than 4.

To solve this with an iterative algorithm, you could do an inorder traversal (using a stack), and verify that every next value in that traversal is not less than its predecessor:

```
def is_bst(node):
    prev_data = None
    q = []  # Not a queue anymore, but a stack
    while True:
        if node:
            q.append(node)
            node = node.left
        elif q:
            node = q.pop()
            if prev_data is not None and prev_data > node.data:
                return False
            prev_data = node.data
            node = node.right
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: The `while true` functions similarly as `if node or q` right? I've seen in order traversal articulated this way before. I think they function the same because if neither node or q, the else statement breaks out the infinite while loop.

Comment: Like `while node or q` yes.